# How to attach ground on a breadboard from a schematic?

Tags: circuit-design, ground, breadboard

I'm trying to build a circuit on a breadboard based on a given schematic, but I'm not sure how to "ground" components on it like how it is shown at node B:

[image: Schematic]

What I have done so far: [image]

What connections do I make and where do I have to make them so as to have a "ground" on the breadboard just like the schematic?

(I'm a beginner at electronics so my non-ground connections may seem off, but I truly have no idea how to work with "ground" connections. I do get the concept of "ground" in theory but I'm having a hard time grasping it practically. Appreciate any help! :))

Comment: The negative supply terminal will be the ground in this case.  Because to measure the voltage we need two points in the space. One of these points is treated as a reference point (GND). We have a very similar situation when we try to measure a height of an object. We need a reference point. The most common reference point is "above mean sea level". But when you measure the height of the table in your house the floor now becomes your reference point. And this reference point has nothing to do with the real "ground"(earth)

Comment: Also, your capacitor is way too small, so you will not observe any interesting effect in the circuit.  And you do not need a switch, you can use a wire. One connects a wire to the positive terminal to charge the capacitor. Next, disconnect it from the positive terminal and connect it to the negative one (GND) to discharge the capacitor.

Comment: The schematic shows a **single pole, double throw** switch (see [Wikipedia: Switch § Contact terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology)). Does that match the switch in the breadboard, i.e., does your switch have *three* terminals—so you can feed the center terminal from either Input A or Input B—or does it have only two—so it is simply on/off? In either case I agree with Sandro that the white wire looks like it shorts out the switch, meaning the circuit behaves the same no matter how you manipulate the switch.

Comment: Note also, for future reference, that the supply lines running up and down the side of the breadboard are usually **not** connected *across* the breadboard, so if you wanted to use the power supply positive on the other side of the breadboard as well you would need to have a jumper wire spanning from some hole on the left-positive-line over to some hole on the right-positive line, and the same for the negative side. In this circuit the lack of those jumpers is irrelevant, but you should be aware of that.

Comment: @randomhead Thank you so much for the explanation! To answer your question, it is a single pole, double throw switch i.e., it has three terminals. The reason why I had connected the white wire was because I thought it would make the "1 to A" connection from the schematic; but I see how that shorts the switch.

Comment: I see. What you want is for the power supply positive to be connected to one input of the switch, the negative connected to the other side (being very careful not to cause a short between the two!!), and the resistor feeding the meat of the circuit connected to the center "output" of the switch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ground is usually just a convention.  In some circuits it might actually be an Earth connection, but that's usually when working with mains (which is dangerous when begining in electronics,) so you won't have to wory about Earth for now.

So basically, the symbol is used for just 2 things :

- To say "this is what I define as my reference (0V) potential", so you can say "at A, I have 10V" (for exemple) instead of havig to say "at A, I have 10V more than at B" (or "I have 10V between A and B). Usually, when we have a single DC supply, we use its "minus" as ground.
- In addition, if you have several ground symbols (not your case,) you know that they all need to be connected together. It is very useful on bigger circuits where you can have dozens or even hundreds of connections to ground so you don't have to draw all those lines.

In your case, everything that is connected to "ground" is simply to be connected to the "minus" of your power supply.

The only thing you are missing is a wire from the negative power supply to the switch. I can't say where it has to be connected to the switch.because I can't tell how the switch works just from the image.

NB: The small white wire looks quite suspicious to me.  Are you sure you need it? It is basically shorting the switch. Is it just the arrow in the switch you tried to implement (that arrow is just supposed to show the position of the switch, not to be an external wire.) If I'm guessing right, with that white wire when you connect the missing wire to the switch, then if the swich is on position 2, you **create a short circuit!** Check that carefully before powering on your circuit.

If needed, ask a new question about if if you still have doubts.

Comment: For full clarity: it seems to me that in the provided schematic the "ground" symbol is superfluous and unnecessary, which may be the source of OP's confusion. That symbol technically means "connect to earth ground" which is surely not necessary for this circuit to function.

Comment: @randomhead I truly am confused about when to actually connect ground on a breadboard/power supply/scope/function generator. Do I always ignore them? I may post another question about ground connections when multiple devices are involved; but thank you to both you and Sandro for the explanations! Really appreciate it!

Comment: As long as you don't work with mains, in 99.9% percent of cases, just connect all grounds together (not connecting grounds is a very commun begginers mistake), and no need to connect "ground" to earth.